# Using a Named Credential to access internal Salesforce URI with UserInfo.getSessionId() returning a 401 error

Tags: apex, rest-api, connected-apps

I want to access the following salesforce rest endpoint using APEX in my org:

`/services/data/v49.0/localizedvalue/records/upsert`

I am using the following Named Credential:

[image]

I was my understanding that I could use `UserInfo.getSessionId()` to authenticate me as I am accessing an endpoint in my instance.

My code is as follows:

```
  public static void createNewSurvey(List<Map<String, String>> payload) {
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint('callout:Update_Survey_Language');
    request.setMethod('POST');
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    //request.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
    request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());

    System.debug('this is a sessionId' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
    request.setBody(payload.toString());
    System.debug('this is the request' + request.toString());
    try {
      HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
      System.debug('this is the response' + response.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.debug(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
```

I receive the following response `[{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]`

Is there a way I can access this endpoint without having to set up a connected app?

Comment: Do you call this from lightning aura/lwc or trigger/visualforce?

Comment: @kurunve so this is getting called from another class but technically its being called from an anonymous apex webhook so its a guest user set up via a site

Comment: Guest user won't give you a valid session

Comment: @identigral I tried to use the following syntax but still running into issues: ```request.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + System.UserInfo.getOrganizationId() + '' + System.UserInfo.getSessionId().SubString(15));```

Comment: I also am getting the same error when running it from a sys admin profile

Comment: `request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId())` will work with the right user license and correct runtime context. Try it in a standalone Apex class without your webhook. You can do so without Named Credential to eliminate another variable although NC shouldn't be an issue here.

Comment: I am still getting a 500 error when using the following syntax and as a system admin. Very strange :/